# how to do line continuation in perl debugger for entering raw multi-line text (EOT)?

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl. I am trying in the debugger to define a variable, which is HERE-DOCUMENT. I do not know how to enter the same code as in the perl script, but to do it in the debugger. Due to new lines present inside the EOT, this makes it hard to do in the interactive debugger.

Here is a small example. I have this script:

```
>cat ex1.perl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $s =<<'EOT';
this is first line
this is the second line
EOT

print $s
```

Now I run it and gives expected output:

```
>perl ex1.perl
this is first line
this is the second line
```

Now I want to do the same in debugger. I tried this:

```
>perl -de0
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
  DB<1> my $s =<<'EOT';\
  cont: this is first line\
  cont: this is second line\
  cont: EOT
Can't find string terminator "EOT" anywhere before EOF at (eval 6)
[/usr/share/perl/5.18/perl5db.pl:732] line 2.
 at (eval 6)[/usr/share/perl/5.18/perl5db.pl:732] line 2.
    eval 'no strict; ($@, $!, $^E, $,, $/, $\\, $^W) = @DB::saved;package 
    main; $^D = $^D | $DB::db_stop;
my $s =<<\'EOT\';
this is first line
this is second line
EOT;
' called at /usr/share/perl/5.18/perl5db.pl line 732
    DB::eval called at /usr/share/perl/5.18/perl5db.pl line 3090
    DB::DB called at -e line 1
```

I do not think using `\` is correct even, but if I do not use `\` debugger will also complain. So I am not sure how to enter the `EOT` text in the debugger.

Is there a way to type in the same thing in the perl script, but using the debugger? I wanted to test things more easily in the debugger on EOT.

I am using

```
>perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for 
x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the `;` after `EOT` in the command that's actually run? That's causing the problem. We'll need to fool the debugger.

```
  DB<1> $s = <<'EOT';\

  cont: abc\

  cont: def\

  cont: EOT\

  cont: 1


  DB<2> x $s
0  'abc
def
'
```